# Determining if the relation is a poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We have this question on our final review sheet and I want to make sure I fully understand it before the exam.
I looked up several examples but they did not help.

Determine whether the following relation

$R =${$(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 5), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5)$}

is a partial order relation on the set $S =$ {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$}

When given the set $S$ what do I look for in determining that $R$ is a relation of the poset. Does the cardinality matter?

Comment: You need to check the properties of a partial order are fulfilled: Reflexive, anti-symmetric, transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the relation is a partial order on the set $S$, since it is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.

A relation is reflexive if it contains all pairs of the form $(x,x)$. It is antisymmetric if the only 'mutually reverse' pairs that it contains are the pairs of the form $(x,x)$. That is, it cannot contain two pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$, with $x \neq y$. Finally, it is transitive if for every couple of pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$, the pair $(x,z)$ is also present.

Obviously, you have all the pairs of the form $(x,x)$, and there is no couple of pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$, with $x \neq y$. For the transitivity you only need to check the triple of pairs $(1,4), (4,2), (1,2)$.

Comment: thanks so much. since we only have the set $S$ is that why it is antisymmetric?

Comment: The relation is antisymmetric because there is no couple of pairs that contradicts it.